# Changing the zoom level in all link destinations in PDFs

Tags: c#, itext

A code that changes zoom level using `iText` in `Java` is given in at [iText home page](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/actions-and-annotations/changing-zoom-factor-link-destination). I would like to convert it to `C#`. After countless hours, I have finally rewritten the code only to find out that it didn't change any link. It means I must have made errors.

EDIT:

As requested, please have a look at a [simple PDF example](http://rgho.st/84HQPbzPg).

My code is as follows:

```
using (var reader = new PdfReader(input))
{
    using (var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms))
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
        {
            // Get a page of a PDF page
            PdfDictionary page = reader.GetPageN(i);

            // Get all the annotations of page i
            PdfArray annotsArray = page.GetAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);

            // If page does not have annotations
            if (annotsArray == null)
            {
                continue;
            }

            // For each annotation
            for (int j = 0; j < annotsArray.Size; j++)
            {
                // for current annotation
                PdfDictionary annotation = annotsArray.GetAsDict(j);

                // test if it is LINK
                PdfDictionary annotationAction = annotation.GetAsDict(PdfName.A);
                if ( annotationAction == null || PdfName.LINK.Equals(annotationAction.Get(PdfName.S)) )
                {
                    PdfArray d = annotation.GetAsArray(PdfName.DEST);
                    if (d != null && d.Length == 5 && PdfName.XYZ.Equals(d.GetAsName(1)))
                    {
                        d[4] = new PdfNumber(150);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Original code in Java is much shorter:

```
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
        PdfDictionary page = reader.getPageN(11);
        PdfArray annots = page.getAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS); 
        for (int i = 0; i < annots.size(); i++) {
            PdfDictionary annotation = annots.getAsDict(i);
            if (PdfName.LINK.equals(annotation.getAsName(PdfName.SUBTYPE))) {
                PdfArray d = annotation.getAsArray(PdfName.DEST);
                if (d != null && d.size() == 5 && PdfName.XYZ.equals(d.getAsName(1)))
                    d.set(4, new PdfNumber(0));
            }
        }
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
        stamper.close();
    }
```

**UPDATED EDIT 2**

Thanks to @mkl I've came up with solution.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
{
    PdfDictionary page = reader.GetPageN(i);

    PdfArray annotsArray = page.GetAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);

    if (annotsArray == null)
    {
        continue;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < annotsArray.Size; j++)
    {
        PdfDictionary annotation = annotsArray.GetAsDict(j);

        PdfDictionary annotationAction = annotation.GetAsDict(PdfName.A);
        if (PdfName.GOTO.Equals(annotationAction.Get(PdfName.S)))
        {
            PdfArray d = annotationAction.GetAsArray(PdfName.D);
            if (d != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(d[4]);
                d[4] = new PdfNumber(1.20);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Your code only handles destinations of type **XYZ**. Probably your example pdf uses other types of destinations. Thus, please share your test pdf.

Comment: @mkl I have just added an example file.

Comment: *`PdfArray d = annotation.GetAsArray(PdfName.GOTO)`* - this is wrong in two ways: you want the array named **D**, not an array named **GoTo**, and this array is contained in the `annotationAction`, not directly in the `annotation`. Thus: `PdfArray d = annotationAction.GetAsArray(PdfName.D)`

Comment: Thanks for this. I've finally made it working. Could you tell me what manual/book/documentation would help me to know which element in `PdfArray d` is the correct one to change? What I did was to loop over each element to find one. Not very clever but it was easy enough to guess that was 4th element (zer0-based).

Comment: *"what manual/book/documentation would help ..."* - the specification ISO 32000, currently part 1 (part 2 is soon to be published); Adobe provides a copy of the specification in which merely the headers and footers are replaced to not mention ISO - http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/flashplayer/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf - where **Link** annotations are specified in section 12.5.6.5 and actions in section 12.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the specification of link annotations, you will see

> **A**
>   dictionary
>   *(Optional; PDF 1.1)* An action that shall be performed when the link annotation is activated (see 12.6, “Actions”).
>
> **Dest**
>   array, name or
>   byte string
>   *(Optional; not permitted if an **A** entry is present)* A destination that shall be displayed when the annotation is activated (see 12.3.2, “Destinations”).

*(Table 173 – Additional entries specific to a link annotation - ISO 32000-1)*

I.e. both the original Java code and your port only handle one kind of **Link** annotations, the kind using a **Dest** entry.

Inspecting your sample PDF, though, one finds **Link** annotations with an **A** entry, e.g.

```
/A <<
    /D  [ 1 /XYZ 0.000001 842 0.724 ]   
    /S  /GoTo   
>>
```

Thus, your code has to consider all possible options. In particular if the PDF you manipulate has an **A**ction defined instead of a **Dest**ination, it has to properly process the **D**estination of the **A**ction instead of merely the non-existent **Link** **Dest**ination.

Comment: Thanks for your directions I was able to find `GoTo` actions.(Well, it took me some times but I have it.) Could you please tell me how do I now change the zoom factor?

Comment: Anybody interested in the actual solution can see my updated post.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you're using a different PDF as input, but using [the source PDF from the iText web site](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/resources/pdfs/xyz_destination.pdf) for the example you linked to in the question, this works for me and changes the zoom level for all links to the document zoom level:

```
using (reader)
{
    PdfDictionary page = reader.GetPageN(11);
    PdfArray annots = page.GetAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);
    for (int i = 0; i < annots.Size; i++)
    {
        PdfDictionary annotation = annots.GetAsDict(i);
        if (PdfName.LINK.Equals(annotation.GetAsName(PdfName.SUBTYPE)))
        {
            PdfArray d = annotation.GetAsArray(PdfName.DEST);
            if (d != null && d.Size == 5 && PdfName.XYZ.Equals(d.GetAsName(1)))
                d.Set(4, new PdfNumber(0));
        }
    }
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, stream)) { }
        File.WriteAllBytes(outputFile, stream.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help! Unfortunately, your code doesn't work against my test file. I am not sure, but I think it uses **XYZ** as a technique to jump to the next page.